# Пропорциональнле уменьшение изображения внутри iframe без javascript

Tags: html, css, iframe

Делаю тут по лабораторному заданию сайт простой на `html+css`. Есть галерея -- миниатюры-ссылки, которые открываются в `iframe`. С уменьшением миниатюр проблем нет, а вот изображения внутри `iframe` никак не масштабируются. Код дичайше нубский. Но это всего лишь лабораторка..

[Сам сайт](http://unit312.zzz.com.ua)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  font-family: jakobctt;
  color: #00AA00;
  background-image: url(../img/bg2.png);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1000;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 170, 0, .1);
}

#body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1080px;
  font-family: jakobctt;
  color: #00AA00;
  font-size: 14 px;
  text-align: left top;
}

.content {
  background: -13px 0 10px -13px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8)inset, 13px 0 10px -13px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8) inset;
  width: 750px;
  float: left;
  position: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 170, 0, .3), -23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8), 23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 170, 0, .1) inset;
}

.resize {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.resize iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  background: gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00aa00), color-stop(1, #005000));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00aa00 5%, #005000 100%);
  background-color: #00aa00;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: jakobctt;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #005000), color-stop(1, #00aa00));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #005000 5%, #00aa00 100%);
  background-color: #005000;
}

.btn:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

#menu {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#menu a {
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: 50% 100%;
}

.fb-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url(../img/frige.png);
  background-size: 240px 390px;
  background-position: middle center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  /*box-shadow:
     0 1px 4px rgba(0, 170, 0, .3),
     -20px 0 20px -20px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8),
     20px 0 20px -20px rgba(0, 170, 0, .8),
     0 0 40px rgba(0, 170, 0, .1) inset;*/
}

footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 1080px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">ШАПКА
</div>
<div id="body">
  <div id="menu" align="center">
    <span class="btn"><a href="../index.html">Главная</a></span>
    <span class="btn"><a href="themes.html">Темы</a></span>
    <span class="btn"><a href="gallery.html">Галерея</a></span>
    <span class="btn"><a href="about.html">О нас</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="https://facebook.com/unit312od" target="_blank" class="fb-link"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="gallery" align="center">
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_1.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_1.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>
      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_2.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_2.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_3.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_3.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>
      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_4.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_4.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_5.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_5.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_6.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_6.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_7.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_7.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_8.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_8.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
      <a href="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_9.jpg" target="frame">
        <img src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_9.jpg" width=10% height=10%/>

      </a>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="resize" align="center">
      <iframe src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_8.jpg" name="frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
     </div>-->
    <div class="resize" align="center">
      <iframe name="frame" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html>
     <img src='../gallery/mountains1920x1080_1.jpg' style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;'/>" src="../gallery/mountains1920x1080_1.jpg" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Content 2
  </div>
  <footer>
    <span>(R) Unit312</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас в header содержится meta + link + title , вот жесть

Comment: Код необходимо прикреплять в вопросе. Переход на внешние ресурсы с сомнительными урлами недопустим в рамках SOF

Comment: Исправил. Код Css и html добавил, ссылку убрал

Answer (score 0):

Под масштабированием вы подразумеваете адаптив?

добавьте

```
#body{max-width:100%;}
.content{max-width:100%;}
```

Comment: Под масштабированием я имею ввиду уменьшение картинки, отображаемой внутри iframe до размеров самого iframe. Во всех браузерах. Частично это работает, кажется, только на фаерфоксе